# category pagination got broken suddenly

Tags: categories, pagination, query

i need some help here please!
The pagination just stopped working suddenly with the default post type and default wp query, with plugin "wp-paginate" or even with next/prev arrows!
It echo 404 error when navigate to any sub page.
Any clues what may cause this ?
thanks

Comment: Please add [debug information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to your question to make answers possible.

Comment: Debugging doesn't provide any clues about this issue! 
i just noticed something: when set rewrite rules to default it works fine but when return  it to the current one (/category/post/) that issue happen !

Comment: Install the [Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) to inspect the current rules. Make sure you don’t use `query_posts()` on the affected pages (disable widgets and all plugins too).